# Manage podcasts outide of iTunes for iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have a rather large list of podcasts I sync with my iPhone couple of times' each weeek. My problmes is however that I have à couple of computer and I cacanr find à good way to update from any of the computer. Is it possible to export import à list of subscription and what other alternatives do i have to manage them?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that it is slightly buggy, I really like [RssPlayer](http://rssplayer.blogspot.com/).  By using RssPlayer instead of getting podcast updates from a computer, you can get you updates directly on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

There's a program called [TouchCopy](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/) that you can buy that lets you manage your iPhone content such as podcasts without using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem until I just went into ITunes on the iPhone and set all my RSS feeds up inside the iPhone itself. No new software, just iTunes on the device